# How can an App write and read file in Documents folder?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

I wrote an App, in Kotlin with Android Studio that write some strings to a file.
All work, I can write and read inside the App, but I can't see the file looking in Documents folder.
How can I use the folder Documents as a storage space?
Thank you

These are the function I use:

```
fun saveTextFile(view: View, nomeFile: String, testo: String, contesto: Context){

    var fileStream: FileOutputStream
    try {
        fileStream = contesto.openFileOutput(nomeFile,  MODE_APPEND)              // OK esegue append
        fileStream.write(testo.toByteArray())
        fileStream.close()
    }catch (e: Exception){
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
}


fun readTextFile(view: View, nomeFile: String, contesto: Context): String{

    var fileInputStream: FileInputStream? = null
    fileInputStream = contesto.openFileInput(nomeFile)
    var inputStreamReader: InputStreamReader = InputStreamReader(fileInputStream)
    val bufferedReader: BufferedReader = BufferedReader(inputStreamReader)
    val stringBuilder: StringBuilder = StringBuilder()
    var text: String? = null
    while ({ text = bufferedReader.readLine(); text }() != null) {
        stringBuilder.append(text)
    }
    inputStreamReader.close();
    return(stringBuilder.toString())
}
```

Thank you, Livio

Comment: Do you want to store you file in the Document folder of android system ?

Comment: Yes, on a mobile phone

Comment: Yeah i understand that you want to store it on mobile phone . But is the Document folder that exist on the system , is it the place where you are interested to store you file ?

Comment: Yes, there, or somewhere I can read/write from other App (Es.: send the file or receive with WhatApp) or PC.

Comment: Since the context of the Question is limited to creating a file and save it in Document folder I am answering for the same . I suggest you to create another Question , for making your application compatible with other applications

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For writing in Documents folder of your device , you just need to make use of MediaStore for the same. You can take input for this function anything that you want like String , bitmap , PdfDocument and other's too .

For Your UseCase you can do the following ,

Global Variable :

```
    private var imageUri: Uri? = null
```

```
    override suspend fun saveDocument(context : Context, text : String) {
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            try {

                val collection =
                    MediaStore.Files.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL_PRIMARY)

                val dirDest = File(
                    Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS,
                    context.getString(R.string.app_name)
                )
                val date = System.currentTimeMillis()
                val fileName = "$date.txt"


                val contentValues = ContentValues().apply {
                    put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, fileName)
                    put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, 
                    "$dirDest${File.separator}")
                    put(MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.IS_PENDING, 1)
                   

}

                }


                val imageUri = context.contentResolver.insert(collection, contentValues)


                withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {

                    imageUri?.let { uri ->
                        context.contentResolver.openOutputStream(uri, "w").use { out -> out?.write(text.toByteArray())
                        }
                        contentValues.clear()
                            contentValues.put(MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.IS_PENDING, 0)

                        context.contentResolver.update(uri, contentValues, null, null)
                    }
                }


            } catch (e: FileNotFoundException) {
                null
            }
        }
    }
```

For Updating the already existing file , do the following . After creating file for the first time I have saved the imageUri in a global variable (If you want to store it permanently / or for a while you can use Jetpack Datastore / Shared Preference to save the same ):

```
 suspend fun updateData(context: Context,text : String){
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            try {

                val collection =
                    MediaStore.Files.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL_PRIMARY)

                val dirDest = File(
                    Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS,
                    context.getString(R.string.app_name)
                )
                val fileName = "test.txt"


                val contentValues = ContentValues().apply {
                    put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, fileName)
                    put(
                        MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH,
                        "$dirDest${File.separator}"
                    )
                    put(MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.IS_PENDING, 1)


                }




                withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {

                    imageUri?.let { uri ->
                        context.contentResolver.openOutputStream(uri, "wa").use { out ->
                            out?.write(text.toByteArray())
                        }
                        contentValues.clear()
                        contentValues.put(MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.IS_PENDING, 0)

                        context.contentResolver.update(uri, contentValues, null, null)
                    }
                }


            } catch (e: FileNotFoundException) {
                null
            }
        }

    }
```

For Reading the File , Do the following :

```
suspend fun read(context: Context, source: Uri): String = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
  val resolver: ContentResolver = context.contentResolver

    resolver.openInputStream(source)?.use { stream -> stream.readText() }
      ?: throw IllegalStateException("could not open $source")
}

private fun InputStream.readText(charset: Charset = Charsets.UTF_8): String =
  readBytes().toString(charset)
```

This is how the final code looks like :

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var btn: Button
    private var imageUri: Uri? = null
    private lateinit var btn2: Button
    private lateinit var btn3 : Button

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        btn = findViewById(R.id.btnAdd)
        btn2 = findViewById(R.id.getText)
        btn3 = findViewById(R.id.updateText)
        btn.setOnClickListener {
            lifecycleScope.launch {
                saveDocument(applicationContext, "Original ")
            }
        }
        btn3.setOnClickListener {
            lifecycleScope.launch {
                updateData(applicationContext,"Appended")
            }
        }
        btn2.setOnClickListener {
            lifecycleScope.launch {
                imageUri?.let { it1 ->
                    val data = read(applicationContext, it1)

                    Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "The data is $data ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show()
                }
            }
        }
    }


    suspend fun saveDocument(context: Context, text: String) {
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            try {

                val collection =
                    MediaStore.Files.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL_PRIMARY)

                val dirDest = File(
                    Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS,
                    context.getString(R.string.app_name)
                )
                val date = System.currentTimeMillis()
                val fileName = "test.txt"


                val contentValues = ContentValues().apply {
                    put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, fileName)
                    put(
                        MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH,
                        "$dirDest${File.separator}"
                    )
                    put(MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.IS_PENDING, 1)


                }


                imageUri = context.contentResolver.insert(collection, contentValues)


                withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {

                    imageUri?.let { uri ->
                        context.contentResolver.openOutputStream(uri, "w").use { out ->
                            out?.write(text.toByteArray())
                        }
                        contentValues.clear()
                        contentValues.put(MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.IS_PENDING, 0)

                        context.contentResolver.update(uri, contentValues, null, null)
                    }
                }


            } catch (e: FileNotFoundException) {
                null
            }
        }

    }

    suspend fun updateData(context: Context, text: String) {
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            try {

                val collection =
                    MediaStore.Files.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL_PRIMARY)

                val dirDest = File(
                    Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS,
                    context.getString(R.string.app_name)
                )
                val fileName = "test.txt"


                val contentValues = ContentValues().apply {
                    put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, fileName)
                    put(
                        MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH,
                        "$dirDest${File.separator}"
                    )
                    put(MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.IS_PENDING, 1)


                }




                withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {

                    imageUri?.let { uri ->
                        context.contentResolver.openOutputStream(uri, "wa").use { out ->
                            out?.write(text.toByteArray())
                        }
                        contentValues.clear()
                        contentValues.put(MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.IS_PENDING, 0)

                        context.contentResolver.update(uri, contentValues, null, null)
                    }
                }


            } catch (e: FileNotFoundException) {
                null
            }
        }

    }


    suspend fun read(context: Context, source: Uri): String = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        val resolver: ContentResolver = context.contentResolver

        resolver.openInputStream(source)?.use { stream -> stream.readText() }
            ?: throw IllegalStateException("could not open $source")
    }

    private fun InputStream.readText(charset: Charset = Charsets.UTF_8): String =
        readBytes().toString(charset)
```

I have three buttons . With the first  I create a file , then the uri gets stored in the global variable . Then onClick of second button I add to the already existing file and then read the file using the third button using the same imageUri stored in the global variable

This is the demo for the same . Check when the buttons are being pressed and the output in the form of Toast at the bottom .

[image]

Comment: If any error occurs , comment for the same

Comment: I am working on it. I am trying to append data to the file. In the line: 
context.contentResolver.openOutputStream(uri, "w").use ... I change "w" to "wa" but the data are not appended, any idea?

Comment: have u used the right extension , ie, .txt

Comment: First try doing with "w" as the mode .

Comment: Yes, using "w" I can write the file (test.txt (I changed the name inside the function)) and I can see it in the folder with the same name of the App. All OK.
I try to go on changing to "wa" as I see on the web, but data are not appended.

Comment: Not yet with the funcion, I read it with other App on the mobile.

Comment: I think I can write only one time the file. If I try to make a second write with different data the file remain unchanged. This may be the reason "wa" don't work.

Comment: You need to submit same fileName for it to write append . Since you are using different file Name it creates another file . Try using same file Name

Comment: I am using the same name file, I changed the function to always use test.txt

Comment: Using "wa", but the same if I use "w", many times I have many files: test.txt  test(1).txt test(2).txt ...   the authorization of the files is -wr, so they aren't read-only.

Comment: I guess i know what wrong you are doing . You are saveDocument, function again to append extra data to the existing file . You aren't overriding the same uri , but creating new uri every time . Check my updated code . I have created imageUri as an  top variable after creating the document for the first time and then used it while appending data to the already existing file.

Comment: Since , you had asked only for creating and reading I hadn't mentioned about how to update the existing document

Comment: sorry, but i don't see significant differences between the above saveDocument and updateData, in fact the behavior is the same: many files created.

Comment: I have performed the above operations and for me it updates the existing file . Can you post your code ?

Comment: I have updated the code . This is the most i can help you friend . The code works completely fine for me

Comment: I suggest you to delete all your existing files which you have created earlier and then again run the code because it is running much fine on my device

Comment: Thanks, I created a new project (Empty Activity) and then I copied you class MainActivity, I have also created the buttons, but some things remain unresolved: lifecycleScope and withContext(Dispatchers.IO). Now I'm investigating this

Comment: Those are part of kotlin Coroutines add their dependency , These make sure that your operations are not happening on the main thread . It is taking place on the IO thread .implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.5.1' Add this dependency

Comment: OK. Thank you very much for your time. Now is working.

Comment: Happy it helped

Comment: what if you close the app and then directly want to read the file you already wrote?
we should find the uri without saving it in a global variable or caching it in sharedPreferences @KaruneshPalekar